# unable to authenticate with digitalocean when using terraform

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean

I was previously able to use terraform 0.11 with digitalocean. I have since updated the terraform version to 0.13.5 and updated the digitalocean provider. However, after this change, I am not able to provision any resource as I am getting a 401 error from digitalocean. I have even tried using a new authentication token but that produced the same result.

```
Error: Error creating droplet: POST https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets: 401 Unable to authenticate you
```

**versions.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    digitalocean = {
      source  = "digitalocean/digitalocean"
      version = "1.22.2"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}
```

I have modified the TF_LOG value but that has not provided any additional details to help debug the issue. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this further?

I have even tried removing the token from the terraform.tfvars file which forces the token to be requested when **terraform apply** is invoked.  However, the result was the same i.e. unauthorized response.

The token is valid as I am able to use it with curl but not with terraform 0.13.5 and digitalocean provider 2.2.0.

Comment: i moved past the password issue - will update this question once I get this working completely

Comment: issue was resolved when i created a new SSH key, added the public key to digitalocean after which I was able to provision resources via terraform.